# strstr to show string before occurance

Tags: php, strstr

I want to get the first bit of the string after the occurrence of the needle like this...

```
$user = strstr('someemail@yahoo.com', '@', true);
```

But this only works with PHP Version 5.3.0, I have 5.2.9
Is there a way I can get the same results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
list($user, $therest) = explode('@',$email);
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `strpos` with `strstr`, but then I saw how much this answer was *already* putting my suggestion to shame.

Comment: Nice answer, Can you still acess the username with $user? or does this store it in a list?