# Why error "Wrong parameter count for strstr()"?

Tags: php

```
function splitsection($string,$start,$end) {
    return strstr( substr( $string, strpos( $string, $start) + strlen( $start)), $end, true);
}
```

I get the following error for some reason:

```
Warning: Wrong parameter count for strstr()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954792/wrong-parameter-count-for-strstr

Comment: Check the [manual](http://dk1.php.net/strstr) that explains that in `5.3.0`: "*Added the optional parameter before_needle.*". That means that to use the last parameter you NEED to use at least PHP 5.3.0 or create your own function that does the same thing.

Comment: @tas9 I see yeah this is because of lower php version, Can anyone help make this function compatible with older versions?

Comment: @PeakDermutag While a strategy like that may work, you will find it immensely hindering, especially when you try to do something that you *can't* do in older versions, like anonymous functions with `use`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP [manual](http://www.php.net/strstr) specifies that the `$before_needle` parameter first was added in `5.3.0`. Therefore, if you use older versions you are applying one too many parameters. Worry not, though, as you can easily replicate the [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/strstr) function using [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/strpos) and [`substr`](http://www.php.net/substr) to make it work in older versions of PHP (`< 5.3.0`):

```
<?php
    function strstr_replica($haystack, $needle, $beforeNeedle = false) {
        $needlePosition = strpos($haystack, $needle);

        if ($position === false) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($beforeNeedle) {
            return substr($haystack, 0, $needlePosition);
        } else {
            return substr($haystack, $needlePosition);
        }
    }
?>
```

**Usage:**

```
<?php
    $email = 'name@example.com';
    $domain = strstr_replica($email, '@');
    var_dump($domain); //string(12) "@example.com"

    $user = strstr_replica($email, '@', true);
    var_dump($user); //string(4) "name"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/ZYzgAl9l)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using an old PHP version. The third parameter is not supported in PHP 5.2 and older. I suggest you use an newer version of PHP like version 5.3, 5.4, 5.5 or 5.6.

The PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) says:

> 5.3.0   Added the optional parameter before_needle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution for YOU:

```
<?php
//Returns Part of Haystack string starting from and including  
//the first occurrence of needle to the end of haystack.

$email  = 'name@example.com';  
$needle = '@';  
$domain = strstr($email, $needle);
echo $domain.'<br />';
// prints @example.com  


//Returns Part of Haystack The way YOU want pre PHP5.3.0  
$revEmail = strrev($email);  
$name = strrev(strstr($revEmail, $needle));  
echo $name.'<br />';  
echo substr($name,0,-(strlen($needle)));  
// prints name
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Update to PHP version 5.3 or newer.

Comment: @Neit I do not have this option because im on shared hosting

Comment: Then change hosts. The host I work for offers shared hosting with a little drop-down menu to choose 5.2, 5.3 or 5.4, and will even be adding 5.5 soon.